# SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP - but only on a few select Systems

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, connection, webserver

I encounter the problem when I try to access the website of my software engineering uni course. On my desktop (Win10), phone and tablet (both Android) I receive a "SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP"-Error when trying to access the site.

The error appears regardless of browser, it seems to be system-wide.
Interestingly enough I can access the site on my laptop (Win10 + Manjaro) and could also access it on my desktops Manjaro partition. I could also access it on my phone in the uni-network - but not using mobile data.
However I am not sure, whether mobile data is to blame, as I logged in with my firefox account before receiving the error. Naturally I assumed it may have something to do with my firefox-preferences, but i am using the same account on my Manjaro Systems as well as the Win10 partition of my laptop. Besides me, none of my friends, except one have this problem.

I ran the URL through multiple different SSL-Checkers and every one of them encountered problems regarding the SSL-certificates. As the problem occures in different networks I can also rule out some router-settings of my home-network being the cause. Have you encountered such an error before and is there anything I can do on my own or is this an issue I should take up with my course-instructor and ask him to take a look at his server?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the browser plugin "HTTPS Everywhere" was causing the problem.

The error occured in different browsers without the plugin because I copy-pasted the https URL. The issue appeared on my phone because of the shared browser history, which autocompleted the URL to the https version. The plugin is not installed on my Manjaro's Firefox, which is a bit strange as I though it would be shared.

Additionally, on Manjaro, Firefox does not suggest the https version of the site for auto-completion - maybe it favors sites opened on the specific device over sites opened on different devices. Either way, it works now.